# moving std::function into another std::function does not invoke move constructor on captured variables

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I have a class `A` that prints out a message when constructed/copied/moved

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string s)
        :s_(s)
    {
        std::cout << "A constructed\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A destructed\n";
    }
    A(const A& a)
        :s_(a.s_)
    {
        std::cout << "A copy constructed\n";
    }
    A(A&& a)
       :s_(std::move(a.s_))
    {
        std::cout << "A moved\n";
    }
    A& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        s_ = a.s_;
        std::cout << "A copy assigned\n";
    }
    A& operator=(A&& a)
    {
        s_ = std::move(a.s_);
        std::cout << "A move assigned\n";
    }

    std::string s_;
};
```

In `main`, I construct an instance of `A`, capture that in a lambda by value, copy that lambda into a `std::function`, and finally **move** that `std::function` into another `std::function`

```
int main()
{
    A a("hello ");
    std::function<void()> f = [a]{ std::cout << a.s_; };
    std::function<void()> g(std::move(f));
}
```

This prints out the following

```
A constructed
A copy constructed
A copy constructed
A destructed
A destructed
A destructed
```

Why is the move constructor of `A` not invoked? Shouldn't the last step of moving `f` into `g` have invoked `A`'s move constructor?

Comment: coliru moves it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9815dc53d6fe8a7e. I doubt the standard stipulates exactly what should happen here, and apparently Microsoft chose to copy instead of move.

Comment: It didn't even invoke the copy constructor. The act of constructing `g` didn't call any constructor of `A`

Comment: You're right; I'd been assuming the second "A copy constructed" came from the construction of `g`, but in fact the first is from the lambda capture and the second is from constructing a `function` out of the lambda.

Comment: And that's true in gcc too except that the move constructor is used to construct `f` there. Neither one appears to be invoking an `A` constructor when `g` is created..

Comment: Just changing the ownership of an object does not require moving it.

Comment: [GCC output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5133933e82010745) and [MSVC output](http://rextester.com/TKLU6743) Always be certain which lines are causing which output, the copies aren't occuring where you think they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy constructor isn't called precisely because you have moved the `std::function`. This is because `std::function` can optionally store the captured values on the heap and retain a pointer to them. Thus moving the function simply requires moving that internal pointer. Obviously MSVC opts to store the captures on the heap and GCC etc. opt to store them on the stack thus requiring the captured values to be moved as well.

**Edit:** Thanks to Mooing Duck for pointing out in a [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021698/moving-stdfunction-into-another-stdfunction-does-not-invoke-move-constructor/27022098?noredirect=1#comment42574095_27021698) that GCC is also storing the captures on the heap. The actual difference seems to be that GCC moves the captures from the lambda to the `std::function` when it is constructed from the lambda.

Comment: It looks like the real difference here is that gcc/clang's version of `function(lambda&&)`, moves the lambda captures, but Microsoft's doesn't.

Comment: @dlf I can't paste the MSVC standard library code here but if you step through this example in the debugger you will see that the line `std::function<void()> g(std::move(f));` calls `function(_Myt&& _Right)` which `std::forward`s `_Right` into `_Resetm(_Myt&& _Right)`  which simply swaps the `_Impl` pointer with `_Right` and set's `_Right`'s to null.

Comment: You will also note that `_Resetm` contains checking to see if the moved values stores it's capture locally and if so it moves the captures.

Comment: Right; but earlier than that, when `f` is constructed from the expiring lambda, gcc moves the captures while vc++ doesn't (there's so much preprocessor in the actual MS code that I can't easily say why). The question was onto something; just not quite what it initially appeared to be.

Comment: @dlf Ah yes, I see what you were saying now. Sorry I was focusing on the wrong line earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Your standard library implementation does not use the small buffer optimization in this case,
hence your function `f` holds a pointer to an *heap allocated* memory region where a copy of `a` is stored. Since you are moving `f` into `g`, there is no reason to perform a deep copy, and the implementation can just move the ownership of the function stored in `f` to `g` (like an `unique_ptr`).

As for the reason why the small buffer is not used here, this *might* be related to the fact that your implementation defines the `function` move constructor to be **noexcept**<sup>†</sup>.

If the move constructor of `function` is noexcept, it can not call any function that might throw, hence the implementation simply refuse to move your object (from the `f`'s small buffer to the `g`'s one) and allocates it on the heap, so that it can just move a pointer in the move constructor/assignment.

Both `libstd++` and `libc++` generate a *copy constructor* call at the `g = move(f)` line if you simply add `noexcept` to `A`'s copy constructor. Surprisingly they both seem to ignore the presence of a `noexcept` move constructor.

---

<sup>†Notice that (at least in the latest draft) the standard mandates `function(function&&)` to be **non noexcept**, but both libstd++ and libc++ implements it as noexcept, I can't check out MSVC at the moment.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a weakness of MSVC's `std::function` move constructor.  I tried your code on Clang 3.3 and it invokes `A`'s move constructor.

Comment: `std::function` isn't invoking the move constructor in clang, gcc, or MSVC.  The OP mislead you.